# Function having all order derivatives that are positive is analytic

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion, analyticity, analytic-functions

If a real function $f$ on an interval $I$ has derivatives of all orders which are positive at every point of $I$, how can I prove that $f$ is real analytic? (That is, it equals the Taylor expansion of itself)

*Edited*: The following is a kind of hint provided by the textbook. Think about a neighborhood of $a$ and Taylor expansion about $a$. For $x>a, f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{f^k(a){\frac{(x-a)^k}{k!}}} + R_{n,a}(x) > \sum_{k=0}^{n}{f^k(a){\frac{(x-a)^k}{k!}}}$ because all derivatives are positive(therefore the remainder term also positive). Then $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{f^k(a){\frac{(x-a)^k}{k!}}}$ is an increasing sequence of $n$ that is bounded above by $f(x)$, therefore converges.

My question about this is:

1. I can understand that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{f^k(a){\frac{(x-a)^k}{k!}}}$ converges, but how do I know that it converges 'to $f(x)$'?
2. How about the case when $x < a$? Each term has alternating sign, so I can't use the above method.

Comment: See Bernstein's Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions

Comment: But isn't it about a function whose $n$th derivatives have alternating signs?

Comment: Derivatives of $f(-x)$ alternate in sign.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with measure theory, so I'm having a difficulty understanding the theorem and its proof.

Comment: I've edited the question.